# Как создать переменные, которые будут видимы в SASS, JavaScript и Jade(Pug)

Tags: javascript, sass, jade, pug

Каким наиболее простым образом можно создать переменные, которые будут видимы в:

- SASS
- JavaScript-файлах (с использованием Webpack и возможностей ES6)
- Jade-шаблонах

Зачем это надо, думаю понятно: меняем имя, например, CSS-класса в одном месте, и оно автоматически подставляется везде. Без этой возможности изменить имя класса в крупном проекте - целая проблема.

Comment: Для таких действий IDE нужны, visual studio например.

Comment: Я использую `NetBeans`. Какие возможности она даёт для решения поставленной задачи?

Comment: Почему вы думаете что изменить имя переменной в крупном проекте проще чем имя css-класса?

Comment: Я так не думаю. Просто в моих последних проектах по мере их развития css-классы приходилось менять постоянно, а соответствующие им имена переменных - в единичных случаях.

Comment: добавил коечто новое в свой ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

создаете файл .env и в нем переменную SOME_ENV_VAR к примеру
`SASS_ENV=blabla`

читаем переменную в компиляторе SASS или JS: `var ENV = process.env.SOME_ENV_VAR || 'default';`

асайним переменную для Jade:

`const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.locals.env = process.env;`

и читаем переменную в Jade `#{env.SOME_ENV_VAR}`

**Дополнение #1**

```
var sass = encodeURIComponent(jsonToSassVars(sassGlobals));
var webpackConfig = {
    module: {
        loaders:[
            {test: /.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass!prepend?data=" + sass}
        ]
    },
}
```

jsonToSassVars - https://gist.github.com/Kasu/ea4f4861a81e626ea308

Update: the previous link is not available anymore, prefer to use https://gist.github.com/ali-master/cb54a3501c0ea29a88a0297cb9533be9

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подходит ли Ваш способ для хранения большого количества CSS-классов, идентификаторов и селекторов? В моих проектах их сотни в каждом.

Comment: Для хранения большого количества CSS-классов, идентификаторов и селекторов, переменные окружения не подходят.

Comment: Переменные CSS нуно хранить в файле переменных LESS или SASS (SCSS), его можно зделать статическим (вонсить и менять вручную) или же динамическим -  а вот здесь уже чего душа пожелает: можно создавтаь его с помощью серверного языка, или суто сделать скрипт на NodeJS.
Можете посмотреть пример в Семантик-УИ [глобальные дефиниции](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/src/definitions/globals)
или здесь в их [модулях](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/src/definitions/modules)

Comment: Насчёт серверного языка - перебор для такой задачи, учитывая, что мы говорим о front-end разработке... Хорошо, если переменные нужно хранить в SASS, значит в SASS, но как _проще всего_ сделать их доступными в JADE(PUG)-файла и JavaScript-файлах? Вы можете привести простейший пример конфигурации, чтобы я или другие чители форума смогли самостоятельно их усложить и применить?

Comment: Как можно без сервер передать переменную из 1 файла во 2? 
Ну возьмите и читайте перменные САСС с помощью Ноды.
Переменные САСС компилируются и никак не попадут на фронт! Только на сервере! Переменные в Джейд идет толкьо от Сервера!


Мне кажется или я вас не помнимаю или вы не совсем понимаете принцип этого.

Comment: Я, видимо, не понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду под "сервером". Взаимодействие "клиент-сервер" имеет место быть после того, как сайт уже опубликован в интернете, но Вы, видимо, говорите про "сервер" не в этом смысле.

Comment: как вариант храните это все в json, а потом вытягивайте по свойству